# how to display the error message as a tooltip in php

Tags: javascript, php

I have created a basic registration form that works with full functionality. The only problem is that errors that appear is quite far on top left of the screen and it looks quite awkward. Along with it looks like it has no relation with the textbox displaying error. i want the error message to be displayed in the tooltip in a way like particular message in a particular textbox.

along with if the user makes a successful login I want him to redirect it to the login page but in my webpage it dies because of this statement.

```
die ("<h2> Welcome</h2>Login to get started...");
```

Please provide an alternative for this too. any help would definitely be appreciated.

```
if ($reg) {
      if ($em==$em2) {
        $e_check = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$em'");
        $checke = mysql_num_rows($e_check);
        $u_check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$un'");
       $check = mysql_num_rows($u_check);
        if ($check == 0 && $checke == 0) {
                        if ($fn&&$ln&&$un&&$em&&$em2&&$pswd&&$pswd2) {

            if ($pswd==$pswd2) {
                               if (strlen($un)>25||strlen($fn)>25||strlen($ln)>25) {
                echo "Username/ First Name/ Last Name cannot exceeds 25 characters!";
              }
                if (strpos($un, " ") !== false){
                  echo "Your username cannot have a space character.";
                }
                if (strpos($em, "@") == false){
                  echo "Invalid Email";
                }
              else {
                if(strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd)<5) {
            echo "Your password must be between 5 and 30 characters long!";
                }
                else{
                   $pswd = md5($pswd);
                  $pswd2 = md5($pswd2);
                  $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', '$un','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','$d','0','Write something about yourself.','','')");
                  die ("<h2> Welcome</h2>Login to get started...");
                }
              }
            }
            else{
              echo "Your passwords doesn't match!";
            }
          }
          else{
            echo "Please fill in all the fields";
          }
        }
      else{
        echo Username already taken or Email already registered
      }
    }
    else{
      echo "Your E-mails doesn't match";
    }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="fname" size="25" placeholder="First Name" />
  <input type="text" name="lname" size="25" placeholder="Last Name" /><br><br>
  <div data-tip="Make Sure you remember your username. You'll need it at the time of login. Your username should not have space in between.">

  <input type="text" name="username" size="56" placeholder="User Name" /></div><br><br>
  <input type="text" name="email" size="56" placeholder="Email Address" />
  <input type="text" name="email2" size="56" placeholder="Please re-enter your Email Address" /><br><br>
  <input type="password" name="password" size="47" height="30" padding="30" placeholder="Password" /><br><br>
  <input type="password" name="password2" size="47" height="30" placeholder="Please re-enter your Password" /><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="reg" value="Sign Up and learn!" />
</form>
```

Comment: Ajax will be better option .

Comment: i am not friendly with AJAX.

Comment: You should get a lot of *new friend*s, like you should lose `mysql_*` as this is deprecated  and `md5()` is not safe for password hashing. Start using `password_hash()` and `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead. You might start being friends with `AJAX` in the meantime as well :)

Comment: yes it would definitely be amazing to be friends with ajax. could you please help me out with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to Customise the error message,Say giving it A red colour
>   or anything. you can add a class to all span blocks. and you can
>   specify attributes of that class . like below

```
<style>
 .help-block
 {
   color: red;
 }
</style>
```

> You can Add some span blocks below each input .give it each a unique id, and make it Hidden by
>   Default. Like Below

```
<input type="text" name="fname" size="25" placeholder="First Name" />
<span class="help-block" id="fname_block" style="display:none;"></span><br>

<input type="text" name="lname" size="25" placeholder="Last Name" />
<span class="help-block" id="lname_block" style="display:none;"></span><br>
```

**In PHP :**

if error is in the first input. ie, fname

```
    echo"<script>document.getElementById('fname_block').innerHTML = 'error in first name';
document.getElementById('fname_block').style.display = 'inline';  </script>";
```

or if error is the second input(ie, lname). then specify the id of span block of that input in the `getelementById` part of the code

don't forget to hide span block if there is not error.

```
document.getElementById('fname_block').style.display = 'none';
```

> IF you use jquery(you just need to add jquery library),the codings
>   will be much simple.

jquery code for the same js code above

```
 $('#fname_block').html('error in first name').show();
```

you can hide an element in jquery like below.

```
$('#fname_block').hide();
```

Comment: no error message is displayed when i tried this code.